# Do I have to use HTTPS protocol for my web widget?

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, cross-domain, cdn

I am writing a web widget. To use it people need to add this code to their html page:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget/script.js"></script>
```

Will my widget load fine if they have `https` domain? If possible - I would not want to change a script URL to `https://example.com/...` because I use CDN and their HTTPS services 2 times more expensive than HTTP ones. But I heard from some guy that if they try to load my script on their HTTPS site - then it will not be loaded because browsers will consider it unsecured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use https://! Today it is very easy and free (Let's Encrypt) to get an SSL certificate. All your users will feel better and you will not have any browser problems.

Answer (score 1):

It will defiantly cause problems. Browsers will have warnings about unsecured page. If a site uses HTTPS and is using HTTP links then it is considered insecure and will have warnings since you aren't using all secure elements.